# The following code doesn't stop looping

Tags: c

```
int search(char *find){
info account;
int check, i = 0;

FILE *file = fopen("accounts.bin", "rb");

while(1){
    fread(&account, sizeof(account), 1, file);
    if(feof(file)){
        check = 1;
        break;
    }
    if(stricmp(account.id, find) == 0){
        check = 0;
        break;
    }
fclose(file);
}
return check;
}
```

My goal here is to return 0 if the ID is in the accounts.bin file, and 1 if it does not exist. I can get a return value of 0 when the entry is in the file, but when it doesn't, it doesn't stop looping.

Any ideas?

Comment: `while(1){` isn't a comparison, basically what you have there is `while(true) {` which, obviously, is always true, meaning it will loop endlessly.

Comment: `info` is undeclared. `FILE` is undeclared. `fopen` is undeclared. `fread` is undeclared. `feof` is undeclared. `stricmp` is undeclared. `i` is unused.

Comment: Your code doesn't check for read errors. `fread` can fail for reasons other than end-of-file.

Comment: Your code closes `file`, then passes it to `fread` in the next iteration. Undefined behavior.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton There are two `break` statements in the loop, both of which are reachable.

Comment: You are closing the file inside of the loop. Obviously any subsequent `fread` will fail/do some nasty things.

Comment: The code I added is just part of a bigger one I have.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Yes, I have, but is that really the recommended way to utilize while statements? I guess if you want to give it the ability to endlessly loop it's useful.

Comment: So I should close the file outside, correct?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton This is an "OK" way. Question of style and personal preference. I don't like it though.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton `recommended way`? By who? You? The `recomended` one is the most effective, readable and logical. Everyone has its own personal preferences.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Yeah I guess I was more asking if it was the most effective way. Doing it this way can lead to a lot of issues if you never hit any of those breaks.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton it does not matter where you have made logical mistakes. Before break or inside the () in the while. Same effect

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I guess you are right. But I believe the most readable way is inside the while statement. As well as the least amount of code actually written

Comment: So use the proper words - IMO instead of recommended which means something completely different than `I think`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken (can't really check without an example `accounts.bin`):

It's because on line 17 you close the file within the loop; then pass the closed file on to fread in the next iteration. You should close the file just above the `return check;`, outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I simply made the mistake of putting fclose inside the loop.

Moved the closing statement to outside of the loop.

```
int search(char *find){
    info account;
    int check, i = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen("accounts.bin", "rb");

    while(1){
        fread(&account, sizeof(account), 1, file);
        if(feof(file)){
            check = 1;
            break;
        }

        if(stricmp(account.id, find) == 0){
            check = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return check;
}
```

Comment: Please fix formatting for my CDO ;)

Comment: Checking `fread` result is still suggested.

Comment: You need to check the return values of `fopen` and `fread` for errors.

Comment: Consider `while (fread(&account, sizeof(account), 1, file) > 0) { ...`

Comment: @Blacksilver I uhh... I don't get it ._.

Comment: @chux I'll consider it